# How to set array objects int json object with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json, model

i want load array objects from multi select control, then i want load model object called "name" with his name and age values, then i want load array from select and load in model object.... but the ng-model from select control not work :/

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="model.name" placeholder="Put your name..." />
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="model.age" placeholder="Put your age..." />

<!--Select pets for model person-->
<select ng-repeat="pets in arrayFromApi" class="selectpicker" multiple>
   <option id="{{pet.id}}" ng-model="model.pets.id">{{pet.name}}</option>
</select>


<script>
   var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
   app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {

    $scope.model = { "name":"", "age":"", "pets" :[ {"id":""} ] };

    $scope.arrayFromApi = function() {
          ......
        this function get id names
     }
 });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to use ng-options.
You can give it a try with ng-repeat but then it should be on option tag only.

Comment: amm ok, but i need set ng repeat in select tag becouse i need id value :/

Comment: you will have the id value. you can use the iterator value in the same tag as ng-repeat. btw looks like you ng-repeat pets and later try to access pet. that should probably be pet in array...

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using ng-repeat on the dropdowns, it casuses some performance issues. instead use ng-options.

And for havint the model with name, age and pets. check the mixData funciton.

```
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="model.name" placeholder="Put your name..." />
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="model.age" placeholder="Put your age..." />

    <!--Avoid ng-repeat in dropdowns-->
    <!--Select pets for model person-->
    <select ng-change="mixData()" class="selectpicker" multiple ng-model="myPets" ng-options="pet.id as pet.name for pet in arrayFromApi">
       <option value="">Select...</option>
    </select>

    <!--<select ng-repeat="pets in arrayFromApi" class="selectpicker" multiple>
       <option id="{{pet.id}}" ng-model="model.pets.id">{{pet.name}}</option>
    </select>-->


    <script>
       var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
       app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {

        $scope.model = { "name":"", "age":"", "pets" :[ {"id":""} ] };

        $scope.arrayFromApi = function() {
              ......
            this function get id names
         }

        $scope.mixData = function(){
           $scope.model.pets = $scope.myPets;
        };
     });
     </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's much better if you use `select` as angular standards `ng-options` with this attribute you can handle everything in your view and multiple type return array to your controller as `{id: n}`

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {

  $scope.model = {};

  //from api
  $scope.arrayFromApi = [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'test'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'test2'
    }
  ];

  $scope.getDetails = function() {
    console.log($scope.model);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="model.name" placeholder="Put your name..." />
  <input type="text" ng-model="model.age" placeholder="Put your age..." />

  <!--Select pets for model person-->
  <select ng-model="model.pets" ng-options="{id: item.id} as item.name for item in arrayFromApi" multiple></select>

  <button ng-click="getDetails()">save</button>
</div>
```